# Operator not applicable to this operand type Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Someone help me to fix this error please.

> [Error] Unit1.pas(39): Operator not applicable to this operand type

code is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  k: Integer;
  broj: Real;
begin
  k := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  if k <= 9 then
    broj := k
  else    
    broj := (k + 10) / 2;

  if k mod 2 = 0 then
    broj := broj / 10
  else
    broj := broj mod 10; // error line

  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(broj));    
end;
```

Comment: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Mod

Comment: I see no good reason to use `Real` here. Why don't you make `j` an `Integer` instead? Then `div` and `mod` will work too: `if k mod 2 = 0 then broj := broj div 10 else broj := broj mod 10;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod operator needs 2 integers. broj is real (float).

Use this instead

```
broj := broj - Trunc(broj / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use `mod` or `div` with floating point types, e.g. `Real`.
Alternatively to [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53432486/5134294)  you can use this.

```
broj := Frac(broj / 10) * 10;
```

or simply `FMod` from `System.Math`

```
broj := FMod(broj, 10);
```